# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Below shown is my code after creating the CSV file, i want to download the file so i am using below code. but its throwing error " Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" at "Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileCSV + "\"");" place. Its downloading but browser not redirecting to same page.

```
string[] header = { "Error Occurred On", "Controller Name", "Action Name", "Exception Occurred", "Stack Trace Description", "InnerException Occurred", "Stack Trace InnerException Occurred " };
```

The code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int e = 0; e < header.Length; e++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(header[e], typeof(string));
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Exception Occurred] LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
DataTable dtFilter = new DataTable();
dtFilter = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
foreach (DataRow row in dtFilter.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileCSV, sb.ToString());

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
if (bytes != null)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileCSV);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What happens before this code? The error in itself is pretty clear.

Comment: Before this using datatable creating csv file. Adding data from datatable to csv.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect after downloading the File, you are attempting to perform 2 actions where you can only do the first.

I suggest that you download the file in a new (popup) window and redirect the main page if required.

**Edit:-**

You could force the download by opening the file-download action using `window.open.`

Example:-

```
<a href="Action/RedirectPage" data-file="Action/DownloadCVS" class="file-download">Download File</a>

<script>
  $(function() {
      $('a.file-download').click(function() {
         window.open($(this).data('file'));
      }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How to do in new popup window. can you share some code example?

Comment: Hi the this problem is resolved, its looping problem. but after download the CSV file, browser not loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP there is a single response for each request. So this error means that you've already send something to response.

Comment: i am doing before download below show function. As i know , i am not sending another requist.                                     DataTable dtFilter = new DataTable();
dtFilter = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
foreach (DataRow row in dtFilter.Rows)
{
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileCSV, sb.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are still looking for an answer, but rather than Response.Flush & Response.End, try HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(). It has solved a lot of my problems when trying to write directly to request stream.

Answer (score 0):

Some few minutes ago I had the the same problem with a file download. I want to share what worked for me.

The most important thing add:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

in the begin of action result.

And, to be honest, I read it here https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1038819/How-to-resolve-this-error-Server-cannot-append-hea