# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. This is when I'm trying to download a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a funcionality for generate Excel file, using some information.
This is what happends when I write mi code.

> "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

```
var atributostrabajador = new[] {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5"};
var table = new DataTable();
foreach (var t in atributostrabajador)
{
 table.Columns.Add(t);                
 var grid = new GridView { DataSource = table };
 grid.DataBind();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",attachment;
 filename=name%20file.xls");                
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 Response.Charset = "";
 var sw = new StringWriter();
 var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 grid.RenderControl(htw);
 Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Where is this code running?

Comment: here is where the error ocurre
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",attachment; 
 filename=name%20file.xls");

Comment: Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847011/server-cannot-append-header-after-http-headers-have-been-sent?rq=1 Are you doing something else, after the posted code?

Comment: fixing mistages, nothing else. Thank man

Comment: Where is this code running? You need to make sure no other response is sent.